# Sylow subgroups of the free product of profinite groups

Tags: reference-request, finite-groups, profinite-groups

I am interested in the Sylow subgroups of the profinite completion of a free product of finite groups.

Is the following naive expectation true ? I assume things like this should be well-known, and am looking for a reference.

> Let $A$ and $P$ be finite groups, and let $\hat{A * P}$ be the profinite completion of the free product of $A$ and $P$. What is known about Sylow subgroups of $\hat{A * P}$ ?

> In particular, if it true that if $P$ is a $p$-group, and $A$ is order prime to $p$, then $P$ is a Sylow subgroup of $\hat{A * P}$ ?

For a group $G$ and an integer $m$, let $G \mod m := G/<w^m:w\in G>$ denote the quotient of $G$ by the normal subgroup generated by $m$-th powers of elements of $G$. I am also interested in the same question for $(A*P)\mod m$, i.e. whether $P$ has to be a $p$-Sylow subgroup under some natural assumptions.

I understand that this question is essentially about whether the kernel of $\hat{A*P}\to (A\times P)$, resp. $(A*P)\mod m\to (A\times P)\mod m$, can have a non-trivial $p$-subgroup.

Comment: No: since most nonabelian finite simple groups are quotients of $C_2\ast C_3$, it means one can arrange the 2-Sylow or 3-Sylow to be arbitrary large. In particular, the 2-Sylow and 3-Sylow of the profinite free product are both infinite.

Comment: Oh right...thanks.  I guess this strongly suggests that there is no structure theory as I want. Still, maybe someone would suggest a useful reference...

Comment: Unless one has something such as "every free product of profinite groups of order $\ge 2$ and $\ge 3$ has its $p$-Sylow free profinite of countable rank"?